# When a particular key is not present in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

From a Dictionary `input_dict={'Name': 'Monty', 'Profession': 'Singer' }`, get the value of a key `Label` which is not a part of the dictionary, in such a way that Python doesn't hit an error. If the key does not exist in the dictionary, Python should return `NA`.

Sample Input:

```
{'Name': 'Monty', 'Profession': 'Singer' }
```

Sample Output:

```
NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get` method of the dictionary. This method never raises a `KeyError`.

```
input_dict.get('Label', 'NA')
```

---

### The syntax of get() is:

```
dict.get(key, value)
```

### get() Parameters

The get() method takes maximum of two parameters:

- key - key to be searched in the dictionary
- value (optional) - Value to be returned if the key is not found. The
  default value is None.

### The get() method returns:

- the value for the specified key if key is in dictionary.
- `None` if the key is not found and value is not specified.
- value if the key is not found and value is specified.

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method is really useful here as it returns none and don't break the system by giving error

Answer (score 0):

import ast,sys

input_str = sys.stdin.read()

input_dict = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

answer=input_dict.get('Label', 'NA')

print(answer)

Answer (score 0):

Final solution can be with use of `Get()`.

```py
import ast, sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_dict = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

answer = input_dict.get('Label', 'NA')
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

### It is working fine

**We use update statement to update the Label and so when call the label, we the value of "NA"**

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_dict = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
input_dict.update({'Label':'NA'})   
answer=input_dict["Label"]
print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast,sys
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_dict = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

input_dict["Label"]="NA"
answer=input_dict["Label"]
# Type your answer here

print(answer)
```